# tinymce is firring on double click

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

Hi all i am using tinymce in my project  it's working but not on single click, it is working on double click.i am not able to crack it why its happening please help ? here is my code.
i found same unanswered question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881494/

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea", //working on double click 
//selector: "#emailTetxs", //working on double click even selector with element class same result
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste imagetools"
],
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

Everything other is fine but problem is double click

```
<form class="cmxform" id="emailForm" method="post" onsubmit="return addemail();">
<textarea  id='emailTexts' name='emailTexts'></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="submit"  class="button">
</form>

function addemail()
{

dataString = $('#emailForm').serialize();

$.ajax(
 {
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    url: "emails/addemail",

    success: function(data)
    {
     alert(data);
    }
});

return false;

}
```